# Can't Find Specific Permissions to assign on Facebook Application Page - instagram_content_publish permission not found

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am creating some small api to help by business to post images from our CRM to instagram and facebook. Currenty I can find `instagram_basic` permission to read from instagram but can not find `instagram_content_publish` from anywhere.

I checked App Review Page From our production which connects to instagram and I also tried to set this permission to my test user on test application and I can not see that from permissions.

Can somebody please tell me why can't I find that specific permission. Without it I can not post to instagram from my app.

Note: Our Facebook page is connected to our instagram account.

As it is documented I have to assign `instagram_content_publish` in order to create posts on instagram https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-instagram_content_publish

Image 1: No such permission found for test user
[image]

Image 2: No such permission found in App Review For production
[image]

Image 3: I can find `instagram_basic` for test user
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of January 27th, 2021 you can now publish to Instagram Business type accounts via the Instagram Graph API. Be sure to check out the restrictions in the documentation.

**Blog Post:**

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/01/26/introducing-instagram-content-publishing-api/

**API Documentation:**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing#endpoints

Answer (score 3):

You don’t get to see or find that permission, because your app is not among those allowed to use publishing functionality to begin with.

Content Publishing is not available to just any 3rd-party apps at the moment, but only to specific partner companies.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing:

> The Content Publishing API is in closed beta with Facebook Marketing Partners and Instagram Partners only. We are not accepting new applicants at this time.

Comment: Ohh! So what you say is that there is no way to publish to instagram through API?

Comment: Unless you are a Facebook Marketing or Instagram Partner already, currently not. It might be that this leaves “closed beta” status at some point in the future, and will be made available to all 3rd-party developers, but there’s no prediciting that.

Comment: The link you specified doesn't work anymore. Since they removed the link, they will not open this API to 3rd party softwares. Bad news for anyone expecting the API to be made public. How fair you are, Facebook.

Comment: I've waited two years for opening of this Closed Beta for my app. There are just a very few that have been accepted and it's killing my business. Big thanks to Facebook!

Comment: NOW big new is here:  it's possible to use instagram content publishing API now: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/01/26/introducing-instagram-content-publishing-api/?__cft__[0]=AZVWznsmABkVjCzvDFZcEiqdWI19YP-la5hrgeEkLMF_jUqO2P3wrJjhLZeGyczrs12Kp8AXzlwFSQmYagY4fCm7LHzbZ-t5bkYdhtLgMRl51xfD-HrUaDnrc39dnB6xY0XORrDrFl6K1-zTdF82XPMg3KoBj8IRQCcsCbM_k1nCeXQkrxJQPZkVcJWyp-10n4GObKkmP_vFAQ2pxE7rurgw&__tn__=%2CmH-R